# project linq group by result into a single view model object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to get the count of a number of entity tables and assign them to a single object which holds the counted values.

I am using a union because I want to execute a single query against the database.

I have written the following code but this will return a separate counts view model for each group by, instead Id like to assign the values to the properties of a single counts view model.

```
var counts =
                _db.Departments.All()
                    .Select(c => new {key = 1, count = 0})
                    .Union(_db.Students.All().Select(c => new {key = 2, count= 0}))
                    .GroupBy(c=>c.key)                  
                    .Select(x => new CountsVm()
                    {
                        DepartmentCount = x.Count(d => d.key == 1),
                        StudentCount = x.Count(s => s.key == 2)
                    });



public class CountsVm
    {
        public int StudentCount { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which will produce one query

```
var countsQuery =
    _db.Departments.All()
        .Select(p => new { key = 1, count = 0 })
        .Union(_db.Students.All().Select(p => new { key = 2, count = 0 }))
        .GroupBy(p => p.key)
        .Select(p => new { key = p.Key, count = p.Count() }).ToList();
var counts = new CountsVm()
    {
        DepartmentCount =
            countsQuery.Where(p => p.key == 1)
                       .Select(p => p.count)
                       .FirstOrDefault(),
        StudentCount =
            countsQuery.Where(p => p.key == 2)
                       .Select(p => p.count)
                       .FirstOrDefault()
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to call count on each entry table separately?

```
var counts = new CountsVm()
    {
        DepartmentCount = _db.Departments.All().Count(),
        StudentCount = _db.Students.All().Count()
    };
```

Comment: the point of the union is to execute a single query instead of executing count for each table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you could do something like: (i've done only using linq, but the return null inside a select it's not a good practice). A foreach would server you better)

```
var countsVm = new CountsVm(){
     DepartmentCount = 0,
     StudentCount = 0
};

var counts =
                _db.Departments.All()
                    .Select(c => new {key = 1, count = 0})
                    .Union(_db.Students.All().Select(c => new {key = 2, count= 0}))
                    .GroupBy(c=>c.key)                  
                    .Select(x => {
                          countsVm.DepartmentCount += x.Count(d => d.key == 1);
                          countsVm.StudentCount += x.Count(s => s.key == 2);
                          return null;
                     });



public class CountsVm
    {
        public int StudentCount { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove All from query and run FirstOrDefault()

```
var counts =
                _db.Departments.
                    .Select(c => new {key = 1, count = 0})
                    .Union(_db.Students.Select(c => new {key = 2, count= 0}))
                    .GroupBy(c=>c.key)                  
                    .Select(x => new CountsVm()
                    {
                        DepartmentCount = x.Count(d => d.key == 1),
                        StudentCount = x.Count(s => s.key == 2)
                    }).FirstOrDefault();



public class CountsVm
    {
        public int StudentCount { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentCount { get; set; }
    }
```